# VBA For each looping function with deleting item

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the code below to loop through invited attendees in an outlook appointment and delete all of them, but it is not working as expected. After deleting one attendee it will then skip the next attendee and delete the one after that. E.g. If attendee one is deleted the code below will then skip attendee 2 and delete attendee 3 and so on. I am looking to have this so it deletes all attendees and not just every other one. Any suggestions?

```
For Each Item In RestrictedItems
    If Item.Class = olAppointment Then
        For Each Attendee In Item.Recipients
                Attendee.Delete
            End If
        Next Attendee
```

Comment: use a for loop and loop backwards?

Comment: You cannot use a for Each loop to delete items in a collection.  The reason for this is that you are changing the collection you are using as your control variable and consequently the internal counter for the control variable gets out of step with the actual members of the collection and this means that some items will not be deleted becuase thier position in the collection has changed due to the deletion of other items.  This is the reason why you have to use a staight for loop and count backwards, so that deleted items do not affect the location of items still to be processed.

Comment: Sorry, how would I go about doing this? I can post my full code if it would be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about your code, possibly -

```
cnt = Item.Recipients.Count
For i = cnt to 1 Step -1
    Item.Recipients(i).Delete
Next
```